# Using the first generalized remarkable limit for evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\sin(x))}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

The first generalized remarkable limit states that $$\lim_{x\to 0,\alpha(x)\to 0}\frac{\sin(\alpha(x))}{\alpha(x)}=1,$$ where $\alpha(x)$ is an infinitesimal.

When evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\sin(x))}{x}$, would it be appropriate to assume that $\alpha(x)= \sin(x)\cong x$ when $x\to 0$, and then substitute $\sin(x)$ to $x$ in the numerator as follows:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\sin(x))}{x}\cong \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1\,?$$

Comment: Perhaps more rigorous to write $${\sin(\sin x)\over x}={\sin(\sin x)\over\sin x}\times{\sin x\over x}$$ and take it from there.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Gerry.